# How to complete the DS-160 when "Session timed out"

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I tried using the latest versions of safari and firefox (mac).

Everytime I try to complete the DS-160 I get a "Session timed out" error.

I can use my application number to login again, but I get a "session timed out" before I can send any new informations.

How to complete my DS-160 application ?

To clarify: Talking about the form on this page https://ceac.state.gov/genniv/

Comment: Have you tried using the browsers' "incognito" or "private" mode? That mode usually disables plugins, bypasses cached/saved data, and ignores cookies, so it's most like trying from a completely new computer.

Comment: Had this when I was doing a US visa app form not long ago. It seemed to time out at 10? 20? minutes. Had to keep hitting save until it timed out, then go back in each time with my ref. Took FOREVER. Worst system.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas i tried. Also made sure to disable all plugins

Comment: @MarkMayo I don’t even have time to input any information to save :(

Comment: You can try [clearing cookies and cached data](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/clear-cookies-and-site-data-firefox) in Firefox, although if the incognito mode didn't work, that may not work either. Another thought is logging in from a different ISP, they may time out your session quicker than usual if there's a lot of requests coming from your IP range. US immigration websites are infamous for being a rotting mess of bugs and ignorance, so if you can't figure it out yourself, contact your local embassy/consulate, they should know all the possible snags you may be hitting in their system.

Comment: I had an identical experience with Chrome and FF. To my surprise, MS Edge on Windows 10 succeeded in first attempt. Not a scientific experiment, just an anecdote, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: I succeeded with Opera. :D

Comment: firefox was doing this, chrome worked

Comment: Safari is explicitly not supported. From ceas.state.gov:

> Use only Internet Explorer 11 or higher, Firefox, or Google Chrome 58 when completing your application. Safari and Microsoft Edge are not supported.

I'm using Chrome in incognito mode for this website. The session seems to expire a little less quickly. Also, the following strategy seems to work well:
1) Whenever a new page opens, fill it with random values accepted by the fields and click "Save".
2) Go back to the page and replace the random values by accurate ones.
3) Hit "Save" every minute.

Admittedly, it's a shame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeeded using Vivaldi; a chromium based browser.

https://vivaldi.com

It uses a different engine than Safari or Firefox so that could've helped

Comment: Could you elaborate on why that would help, instead of just Chrome, or the ones suggested before?

Comment: @MarkMayo I think Chrome would've worked just the same. I did not try

Comment: Had to switch from mac to windows machine and Internet Explorer, don't forget to keep saving, what a burden!!